# How to deploy and use Redis in cloud foundry?

Tags: redis, cloud-foundry, high-availability, service-broker

I am sort of new to cloud foundry. I have some queries -

1. Can I use REDIS as a service in Cloud Foundry , if yes , how. Do we need service broker as well for that.
2. Manifest file for deploying Redis on Cloud foundry in openstack Neutron.
3. Can I do HA of Redis service in CF.

I have been through these links as well
https://github.com/pivotal-cf/cf-redis-release
https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/redis-boshrelease

and deployed redis with a dedicated node and broker but not sure how it will work with an app.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can use Redis as a service in CF, and yes, you'll need to make sure that there is a service broker -- in fact, having a service broker is the ***definition*** of something being a CF Service (if you can write a service broker for it, you can use it as a service). [Here's an overview of the CF Service Broker API](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/). Once you have your Redis cluster and service broker set up, you'll need to do the following:

   - Register your service broker with `cf create-service-broker redis-broker <username> <password> <url to service broker>`.
   - Create a service instance: `cf create-service redis <redis-plan-name> myRedis`
   - Bind your app to the service instance: `cf bind-service myApp myRedis`
2. Building a manifest file depends on which Redis release you use. The `cloudfoundry-community/redis-boshrelease` has a [template for generating an openstack manifest](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/redis-boshrelease/blob/master/templates/infrastructure-openstack-nova.yml). Unfortunately, that release doesn't have a service broker so you can't use that redis as a service in CF. The `pivotal-cf/cf-redis-release`, on the other hand, *does* have a service broker. Maybe you can use the Openstack-specific properties from the `cloudfoundry-community/redis-boshrelease` to make an Openstack manifest for `pivotal-cf/cf-redis-release`?
3. I don't know too much about HA Redis. You'll have to get some help from Redis experts, but I do know that there's a piece of software called Sentinel that's meant to get Redis to HA. You should take a look at that and see if you can extend the release to include Sentinel.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, that was of great help .... I have made manifest for Neutron for pivotal-cf/cf-redis-release ans successfully deployed Redis in CF.         Now If HA is complex to go for right now... Do we have any service broker written for Redis cluster ( master-slave).

Comment: How can we use multiple redis instances with one app ? have you any idea ?